# Automapper is mapping incorrectly?

Tags: automapper

I have two objects, Project is a DB entity and IProject which I am trying to save to the database:

```
public interface IProject
{
    int ProjectID { get; set; }
    string JobNumber { get; set; }
    string JobName { get; set; }
    string ProjectLocation { get; set; }
    int? FeeTypeID { get; set; }
    decimal? Fee { get; set; }
    decimal? ConstructionCost { get; set; }
    decimal? CostPerSquareFoot { get; set; }
    decimal? SquareFoot { get; set; }
    string Memo { get; set; }
    DateTime? DateCompleted { get; set; }
    int JobStatusID { get; set; }
    int ProjectTypeID { get; set; }
}

//The inheritance is actually in a partial class that doesn't get overridden

 public partial class Project : IProject
{
    public Project()
    {
        this.ProjectContacts = new HashSet<ProjectContact>();
        this.ProjectConsultants = new HashSet<ProjectConsultant>();
    }

    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FeeTypeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Fee { get; set; }
    public int JobStatusID { get; set; }
    public string Memo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Acreage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SquareFoot { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ConstructionCost { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> BudgetPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ActualPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCompleted { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> CostPerSquareFoot { get; set; }
    public string ProjectLocation { get; set; }
    public int ProjectTypeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PhaseID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ArchitectID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ManagerID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ArchiveLocationID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectContact> ProjectContacts { get; set; }
    public virtual FeeType FeeType { get; set; }
    public virtual JobStatu JobStatu { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectConsultant> ProjectConsultants { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual ArchiveLocation ArchiveLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Phase Phase { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectType ProjectType { get; set; }
}
```

I have my Map created:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IProject, Data.Project>();
```

but for some reason whenever I call the map:

```
//mappingService is a wrapper I have around Automapper so that I can inject it
var project = _mappingService.Map<IProject, Data.Project>(request);
```

I get this error:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
RuntimeType -> FeeType
System.RuntimeType -> Renaissance.Data.FeeType

Destination path:
Project.FeeType.FeeType

Source value:
System.Decimal
```

I am not at any point trying to do that. The names match and even if I specifically tell it to map with:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Fee, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Fee))
```

It still errors with the same message.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
This works:

```
 .ForMember(dest => dest.FeeType, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

I think it is a hack that I need to do that. I shouldn't have to ignore a property in the destination that does not exist / is not named the same as something in the source property.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly cast both items to `IProject` when performing the map? I tried to create a sample that would mirror the behavior you're seeing here, but couldn't duplicate your bug. I'm using AutoMapper 3.3.1 obtained via NuGet and setting up a map of only interface to interface works for me if I explicitly cast beforehand (`Mapper.CreateMap<IProject,IProject>();` would be your analogue).

Comment: @meklarian  so instead of saying Mapper.Map<IProject, Project>(project);  You are saying do Mapper.Map<IProject, IProject>(project)? and then create a map from IProject to IProject?

Comment: Yes. That should prevent you from having to do memberwise ignore. I can post my sample as an answer if you like.

Comment: @meklarian That doesn't work because on the layer I am passing the result to is attempting to save to the db. IProject is not a valid entity. I need the acutal Project object there. I can Cast it but that also seems hacky

Comment: Ah, in that case you'll probably have to continue suppressing the `FeeType` field. What version of AutoMapper are you using?

Comment: @meklarian Automapper version 3.3.1.0